# change line type for missing values (third variable)

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I try for so long but still I don't know how to do it. I have a data frame:

```
year <- c(1995:2012)
salary <- c(702, 873, 1061, 1239, 1706, 1923, 2061, 2133, 2201, 2289, 2380, 2477, 2691, 2943, 3102, 3324, 3399, 3521)
miss <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df.salary <- data.frame(year, salary, miss)
```

And plot:

```
ggplot(df.salary, aes(year, salary)) +
  geom_line(lwd=1, color="#333333") +
  ylim(c(0, 4000)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1995:2012)
```

Variable miss means, that two values (for 1998 and 1999 are missing and they are only assessed). I would like to point it in my plot using the dashed line between missing years.
I want my plot to look like:

[image]

How can I do it? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your data.frame to have a segment label:

```
toExtend <- function(x) c(diff(x),0)==1 |  c(0,diff(df.salary$miss))==-1
df.salary <- df.salary[rep(1:nrow(df.salary), times=ifelse(toExtend(df.salary$miss), 2, 1)),]
df.salary$miss[toExtend(df.salary$miss)] <- 1
df.salary$seg <- cumsum(c(0, diff(df.salary$miss)!=0))
```

This goes up every time the "miss"ingness changes.  You can now group by this, and add a linetype corresponding to missingness, by changing your "aes" to

```
aes(year, salary, group=as.factor(seg), lty=as.factor(miss))
```

You may want to duplicate rows in your data.frame to extend the segments to each other - it's not clear whether you want to expand the `miss=1` section outwards, the `miss=0` sections inwards, or extend each segment to either the left or the right, but it should be fairly straightforward to do this - make a comment on how you want to bridge the gap if you can't see how to do it.

Comment: yes, I want to expand `miss=1`, so dashed line should be longer. Ok, I managed it :) Thank you!

Comment: I've added code so that we find which rows are nonMissing, but next to  missing.  They get duplicated, and the duplicated ones get their missingness set to 1